# Why there are AC timing characteristics but not DC in I2C interfaced chip?

Tags: serial, i2c, eeprom, timing, ac-dc

I'm quite newbie in electronics, and I'd like to learn why there are AC timing characteristics to [this particular
EEPROM (24LC512)](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21754M.pdf) that I'm using but none for DC?

Does AC timing constraints apply to DC as well?

If not so, do I need to obey any timing constraints in my design if I
were to use I2C bus with DC power supply for this chip?

Comment: There is no such thing as DC timing, because DC means the signal is never changing. Timing characterisics are called AC characteristics because the signal is changing. Nothing to do with AC vs DC power suply.

Comment: DC characteristics are the things that dont require timing information, such as min/max supply voltage, max supply current demand, pin capacitance, switching threshold voltages,etc. AC characteristics are time-related.

Comment: @MarkU Aha! But it is indeed strange way to tell this. I mean why on earth they don't call that timing constraints as just "Timing", ridiculous though :)

Comment: The DC characteristics are usually in a section called "Electrical Characteristics". These basically tell you what DC voltage to apply to the chip. No timing as DC is 0Hz.

Comment: In fact in that particular datasheet, Table 1-1 is actually labelled "DC Characteristics", and Table 1-2 is labelled "AC Characteristics".

Comment: @TomCarpenter yeah, I was used to Electrical characteristics until now, rather than this strange way of telling, I mean at least for me :)

Comment: @MarkU Post it as an answer, I'll check it

Comment: "Timing" could mean "sequencing" and sequencing isn't necessarily an AC thing at all. AC characteristics is the best name.

Answer (score -1):

DC is simply constant w.r.t TIme.So there is no need of Timing characteristic for DC unless and until You are using a fixed vale of DC.
One variable must be present for Timing(lets say U are varying the DC level or u r varying the Load and want to  measure the current)

So..no need of Timing for DC.